# Virtual Com 1 or 2 port over USB on Windows

Tags: windows-7, led, usb-2

I have an LED sign that connects via a RJ11 connection.  I have a USB adapter that goes from USB to RJ11, however when I pull up the software there is no connection to the sign becuase it is looking for a com port.  Any one know how to setup a virtual com 1 or 2 port on windows 7 x64?

Here is a pictures of the actual adapter:

[image]

Comment: Is the adapter just a plug adaptor (just a cable with connectors on each end) or a USB to serial adaptor (that has a box containing circuitry)?

Comment: Hopefully that helps a litte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an actual [USB to RS-232 adapter](http://www.altex.com/Aten-USB-to-Serial-Converter-UC232A-P148718.aspx) and an [RJ11 to DB9 adapter](http://www.altex.com/Modular-Adapter-Kit-w-Thumb-Screws-DB9-Female-RJ-12-6P6C-MA9F-6TS-P140541.aspx) and a standard USB A-B cable and a standard gray phone cable (four conductor).

[image][image]

Comment: Dang I was scared that may be the answer.  What's the difference though between this setup and my adapter above?

Comment: @KronoS: The adapter you show has no electronics to convert the signal between USB and RS-232.